# ViewModel with List<BaseClass> and editor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, model-binding

I have a view that lists tables being added to a floor plan. Tables derive from `TableInputModel` to allow for `RectangleTableInputModel`, `CircleTableInputModel`, etc

The ViewModel has a list of `TableInputModel` which are all one of the derived types.

I have a partial view for each of the derived types and given a `List` of mixed derived types the framework knows how to render them.

However, on submitting the form the type information is lost. I have tried with a custom model binder but because the type info is lost when it's being submitted, it wont work...

Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: I think this will work: http://www.codinginstinct.com/2010/03/aspnet-mvc-and-convention-based-forms.html

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Assuming you have the following models:

```
public abstract class TableInputModel 
{ 

}

public class RectangleTableInputModel : TableInputModel 
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class CircleTableInputModel : TableInputModel 
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new TableInputModel[]
        {
            new RectangleTableInputModel(),
            new CircleTableInputModel()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TableInputModel[] model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Now you could write views.

Main view `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model TableInputModel[]
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and the corresponding editor templates.

`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/RectangleTableInputModel.cshtml`:

```
@model RectangleTableInputModel
<h3>Rectangle</h3>
@Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
```

`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/CircleTableInputModel.cshtml`:

```
@model CircleTableInputModel
<h3>Circle</h3>
@Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bar)
```

and final missing peace of the puzzle is the custom model binder for the `TableInputModel` type which will use the posted hidden field value to fetch the type and instantiate the proper implementation:

```
public class TableInputModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".ModelType");
        var type = Type.GetType(
            (string)typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof(string)), 
            true
        );
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);
        return model;
    }
}
```

which will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TableInputModel), new TableInputModelBinder());
```

and that's pretty much all. Now inside the Index Post action the model array will be properly initialzed with correct types.

Comment: Cheers man, looks like I wasn't far off the Mark. Your assumed code is spot on :)

Comment: Does it matter that the array of TableInputModel are a part of a larger InputModel - rather than being used as direct params on the post action?

Comment: @iwayneo, no, the array could be a property of another view model. You just might need to look and tweak the prefix at the model binder.

Comment: hmmmmm... i have an issue then. i had tweaked it slightly to look like: http://monobin.com/__ff95e3f3 but it never gets called - i assumed it was because it wasn;t the topmost viewmodel... now i have no idea

Comment: @iwayneo, how does your main view model look like?

Comment: OK - i did a test project: https://github.com/wayne-o/BindingTest and that works as expected... i need to peel back my real project and figure out what's stopping it from working there. thanks for your help.

Comment: finally fixed this - i was defaulting the NewTable in the default ctor!!! durrrr :D

Comment: Just for the records: `bindingContext.ModelName` might be empty so you have to remove the dot before the Propertyname in that case.

Answer (score 2):

There was ["Derived Type Model Binder"](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DerivedTypeModelBinder&referringTitle=Documentation) in mvccontrib. But, unfortunately, there is no such binder in mvccontrib version 3

Comment: Actually it is, but API is changed significally in comparison with mvccontrib2