# Custom model binding on derived property not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a custom ModelBinder (MVC3) that isn't getting fired for some reason.  Here are the relevant pieces of code:

**View**

```
@model WebApp.Models.InfoModel
@using Html.BeginForm()
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Truck)
}
```

**EditorTemplate**

```
@model WebApp.Models.TruckModel
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CabSize)
```

**ModelBinder**

```
public class TruckModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TruckModel), new TruckModelBinder());
    ...
}
```

**InfoModel**

```
public class InfoModel
{
    public VehicleModel Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

**VehicleModel**

```
public class VehicleModel
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
}
```

**TruckModel**

```
public class TruckModel : VehicleModel
{
    public int CabSize { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(InfoModel model)
{
    // model.Vehicle is *not* of type TruckModel!
}
```

Why isn't my custom ModelBinder firing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to associate the model binder with the base class:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(VehicleModel), new TruckModelBinder());
```

Your POST action takes an InfoModel parameter which itself has a Vehicle property of type VehicleModel. So MVC has no knowledge of TruckModel during the binding process.

You may take a look at the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484972/viewmodel-with-listbaseclass-and-editor-templates/6485552#6485552) of an example of implemeting a polymorphic model binder.

Comment: Perfect, makes sense now. Thanks Darin.

Comment: Quick follow up.  I tried this, and it works for the most part, except my model values are all coming back default/null.  I will update the code in my OP with that I have now.

Comment: Never mind, I'm going to mark this as the answer, as it resolved my original issue of the custom ModelBinder not being bound properly.  I'm rolling back my edit and will create a new question on this new issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087274/polymorphic-custom-model-binder-not-populating-model-w-values).