# Submit a form with multiple objects to the Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, asp.net-core

**The problem:**

I have a view which has multiple tab-panes. Each tab-pane correspond to a `Store`.

Inside each tab-pane (`Store`) there is a table which contains information of all the `Devices` assigned to that Store . The information of each `Device` (each `Device` belongs to a `Machine`) is presented in a row.

Each row is wrapped as a individual form at the moment but this is subject to change.

I'm looking for a way to save each row as an independent object while sending them all to the Controller.

**What I know:**

I'm very new at ASP.NET Core but I can discard sending multiple forms since this is, I believe, not possible. However, I don't know how, if I send all the information wrapped in a single form, how to iterate thru each element and save each one separately.

**The design:**
[image]

**The Controllers:**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var Tiendas = await _context.Stores.Where(t => t.Usuario == User.Identity.Name)
            .Include(t => t.Machines).ThenInclude(t=>t.MachineTypes).ThenInclude(t=>t.MachineFamilies)
            .Include(t => t.Machines).ThenInclude(t => t.Devices)
            .Include(t => t.Machines).ThenInclude(t => t.MachineTypeIncomes)
            .Include(t => t.HechosLiquidadors).ToListAsync();

        SalesIndexData Liquid = new SalesIndexData()
        {
            StoreL = Tiendas,
        };

        return View(Liquid);
    }
```

**The view:**

```
@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.LiqIndexData

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        @foreach (var item in Model.StoreL)
        {
            @if (item.StoreLastLiq != Model.CurrentDate)
            { 
            <li><a href="#@item.StoreID" data-toggle="tab">@item.StoreName</a></li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
@foreach (var item in Model.StoreL)
{
  <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="@item.StoreID">
        <table style="width:100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><div>Machine Model</div></td>
                    <td><div>Sales</div></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var store in Model.StoreL.Where(s => s.StoreID == item.StoreID))
                {
                    @foreach (var machine in store.Machines)
                    {
                        @foreach (var device in machine.Devices)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                 <td>
                                     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => machine.CoinValue)
                                </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div>
                                            <input id="@device.DeviceName"                                                 type="number" min="0" step="1" asp-for="@Model.SalesAmount" name="SalesAmount"  />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.SalesAmount" class="text-danger field-validation-valid"                                                data-valmsg-for="Cortesia" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }                             
                      }
                  }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a id="AddLiquidacion" asp-action="Index" method="post" class="btn btn-default">
                Grabar Liquidación
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Looking for any advice on how to tackle this issue. I would like to keep the design and avoid creating a separate view for each `Device` and save each one separately if possible. JQuery may come in hand for this task?

Comment: Have you considered sending JSON or is it requirement limitation? Also, can you show us your Post action on the controller?

Comment: @Rob I haven't work with JSON, wouldn't know how to apply it here. At this moment I don't have anything at my Post action method since I don't know how to iterate thru the elements inside the form

Comment: I would than suggest you start looking at jQuery. You could easly iterate through your rows and populate a JSON object which can, in your case, be a list of row objects. That list of JSON object can than be sent to server via jQuery ajax method. Basically, you wouldn't have to change much on the server side, just on the client side. Im sure you can find some good tutorials on jQuery, JSON and AJAX as it is very common to use this to send data to server.