# MVC2 Ajax Form Submission causes 'Cannot create an instance of an interface' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems submitting a form via AJAX to my controller. Other people with similar error message seem to have issues around using interfaces as types on their controller method stub, I don't have that issue. I've included my partial view and controller code, if I missed any information out just let me know. I suspect it has something to do with the creation of the model after I change the value in the drop down list, but the error message isn't the most helpful so I'm a bit stuck!

My Partial View:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("RequestDetails", "Home", new { RequestId = Model.Request.RequestId, RequestStatus = Model.Request.Status }, new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "Details"
        },
        new { @class = "jqtransform" }))
        {%>

        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Request.Name) %>
        <p><%= Html.Encode(Model.Request.Name)%>&nbsp;</p>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Request.Status) %>
        <% if (Html.IsAdmin(this.Page))
        {%>
            <div class="rowElem">
            <%=Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Request.Status, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["requestStatus"], null, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%>
            </div>
    <%  }
        else
        { %>
            <p><%= Html.Encode(Model.Request.Status.GetStringValue())%>&nbsp;</p>
        <% } }%>
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult RequestDetails(RequestDetailModel model, Guid RequestId, string RequestStatus)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RequestMethods requestMethods = new RequestMethods();

            IRequest request = _requestRepo.GetRequestById(CurrentUser, RequestId, CompanyId);

            requestMethods.UpdateRequestStatus(request, CurrentUser, model.NewComment, model.Request.Status);

        }

        model.Request = _requestRepo.GetRequestById(CurrentUser, RequestId, CompanyId);

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

The exact error thrown is:

Cannot create an instance of an interface.


at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder) at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown your `RequestDetailModel` object but if there are properties that are interface type the default model binder is not able to populate them. For example if you have the following:

```
public class RequestDetailModel 
{
    public IRequest Request { get; set; }
}
```

where `IRequest` is an interface or an abstract class this won't work. If you want to use interfaces in your models you will need to write a custom model binder. Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485552/29407) of such custom model binder that works with abstract classes but interfaces would be the same.

Comment: You were right, instead of using an interface I fully fleshed out my model to get access to all the properties I needed. Thanks!