# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Bind model to a List<> that contains different types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to work out how to bind a model that contains a list of multiple object types to a postback action in ASP.NET MVC 3.  I've got the following classes that define a list a vehicle types:

```
public enum VehicleType
{
    Car,
    Plane.
    Boat
}

public class BaseVehicle
{
    public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Passengers { get; set; }
}

public class Plane : BaseVehicle
{
    public int WingSpan { get; set; }
    // -- etc --
}

// Properties omitted
public class Car : BaseVehicle {}
public class Boat : BaseVehicle {}

public class VehiclesViewModel
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public List<BaseVehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

The above classes are displayed by these views:

```
<!-- VehiclesView.cshtml - loaded by the controller -->
@model Mvc3Test.Models.VehiclesViewModel
<h2>Vehicles</h2>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Notes)
<hr />
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Vehicles)

<!-- BaseVehicle.cshtml -->
@model BaseVehicle
@using Mvc3Test.Data
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.VehicleType)
@{
    if (Model.VehicleType == VehicleType.Car)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("Car", (Car)Model);
    }
    else if (Model.VehicleType == VehicleType.Plane)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("Plane", (Plane)Model);
    }
    // etc..
}

<-- Plane.cshtml -->
@model Mvc3Test.Data.Plane
<h2>Plane</h2>
<p>Name: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)</p>
<p>Passengers: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Passengers)</p>
<p>Wingspan: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.WingSpan) metres</p>

<!-- Car.cshtml omitted -->
```

I don't know it the above is the best way to handle the displaying (especially the if statement within a view), but it works for now.  The problem is how to bind back to the viewmodel class.  I've tried replacing the Html.TextBorFor() with Html.TextBox() so I can add binding prefixes ("Vehicles.Car" etc..) but there does not seem to be a way of getting the default model binders to determine what kind of class is being represented in the html so the right type can be instantiated.

I think I'll have to write a custom model binder to work it out - is this the right method to use or is there another way I've missed?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484972/viewmodel-with-listbaseclass-and-editor-templates should help you.

Comment: @AFinkelstein sounds like a duplicate to me.

Comment: Yeah - it's a dup - sorry - I didn't come across the other question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

```
if (Model.VehicleType == VehicleType.Car)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("Car", (Car)Model);
    }
    else if (Model.VehicleType == VehicleType.Plane)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("Plane", (Plane)Model);
    }
```

Can be omitted with EditorFor.Works just fine.

As for binding back - IMO best way is to create custom model binder.

Example:

```
public class DerivedTypeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var typeName = GetVehicleType(bindingContext);
            if (typeName  != null)
            {
                var modelType = Type.GetType(typeName);
                var targetTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
                bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext
                                     {
                                         ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => targetTypeInstance, modelType),
                                         ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,
                                         FallbackToEmptyPrefix = bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix,
                                         ModelName = bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix ? string.Empty : bindingContext.ModelName,
                                         ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider,
                                     };
            }
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
        private string GetVehicleType(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "." + "VehicleType");
            if (valueResult == null && bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix)
            {
                valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("VehicleType");
            }
            return valueResult == null ? null : valueResult.AttemptedValue;
        }
    }
```