# Custom Model Binding MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, deserialization, model-binding

I'm trying to pass a list of JSON objects to a controller method, and automatically have the correct types defined and populated in the controller.

JSON Posted to controller:

```
{ Type : 'Image', ImageName : 'blah.jpg' },
{ Type : 'Text', Text: 'Hello', Font: 'Some Font' }..
```

The Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveCOntent(IList<Item> content)
```

So the impression i've got is that I need to use ModelBinding to convert the elements into the correct type. I've tried following another suggested post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484972/viewmodel-with-listbaseclass-and-editor-templates), which works in a way.. I get a list of the correct 'types' but all the properties are set to defaults and not populated.

I've tried extending the DefaultModelBinder with the following:

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var typeName = (string)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".ItemTypeName").ConvertTo(typeof(string));

        if (typeName == "LINK")
        {

            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => new Link(), typeof(Link));

            base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
        else if (typeName == "IMAGE")
        {
            //bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => new Image(), typeof(Image));
            //base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            return null;

        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
```

Now this works fine for the first type (Link), but as soon as I try to do the same for Image I get an error stating

An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: I found out what was causing the same key error, basically had two properties with the same Name at different levels of the inheritance..

Still wonder if there is a better way of doing this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it works fine and my issue was with the base class of this object having a property with the same name.