# How to use UIHint attribute for property type of interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, interface

I have the next view model:

```
public class PickUpLocationViewModel 
{
    public DateTime PuDate {get;set}

    public IAddressViewModel {get;set;}
}
```

Depends on implementation of IAddressViewModel I want to use appropriate UIHint("Airport"), UIHint("Seaport") etc.. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extra property on the IAddressViewModel of TemplateName like so:

```
public interface IAddressViewModel
{
    string TemplateName { get; }
}
```

So then for each class that implements IAddressViewModel you can define a separate template name like:

```
public class SeaportAddressViewModel : IAddressViewModel
{
    public string TemplateName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Seaport";
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can use one of the overloads of EditorFor like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Address, Model.Address.TemplateName)
```

This should cause it to use the editor template called Seaport.cshtml.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you have the following models:

```
public class PickUpLocationViewModel 
{
    public DateTime PuDate { get; set }

    public IAddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
}

public class AirportAddressViewModel: IAddressViewModel
{
    public string Terminal { get; set; }
}

public class SeaportAddressViewModel: IAddressViewModel
{
    public int DockNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and then a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    var model = new PickUpLocationViewModel 
    {
        Address = new AirportAddressViewModel { Terminal = "North" }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and a corresponding view:

```
@model PickUpLocationViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Address)
```

Now you could define the corresponding display/editor templates:

`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AirportAddressViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model AirportAddressViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Terminal)
```

`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SeaportAddressViewModel.cshtml`:

```
@model SeaportAddressViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DockNumber)
```

Now based on the concrete type, ASP.NET MVC will automatically use the correct template.

And when it comes to binding back you will need a custom model binder. I have illustrated one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485552/29407