# MVC Model Binding and Casting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, casting, model-binding

Lets say I have two classes one derives from the other:

Animal and Dog

```
public class Animal
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Boolean HasSpots { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I pass an animal to the Index view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new Dog() {Name = "Dog"});
}
```

Index - I cast the Animal that was passed in to an Editor Template that takes a Dog.

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Animal

@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x =>  x, "Dog", "Animal")

    <input type="submit" value="Begin" />
}
```

This works fine like it should but when I try to explicitly cast back to a Dog in my controller when I post it to About it won't cast. I Imagine that I'll have to create a custom model binder but I have no clue on how to do that. Or if I'm just missing something entirely. Any way around this without including an interface.

(Using this as a small test example my actual classes are a little more complex)

Comment: why not just set the view's model type as `Dog`?

Comment: Because this is just an example showing the problem. I would do that though if I could

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default model binder doesn't try to guess if you are posting a more derived class than it is expecting.  So even if you have form has fields for a more derived class, if the action is expecting class animal, it will create animal and you will not be able to cast to dog, since a dog was never created.

I don't see a way for an interface to help you here.  If you make your action accept an interface or abstract class, the default model binder will throw an exception due to it not being able to instantiate the said types.

A custom model binder can deal with this situation for you. All the approaches I've seen involve getting some extra meta data into the mix.

An example using an additional form field to hold actual type is here.  [ViewModel with List<BaseClass> and editor templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484972/viewmodel-with-listbaseclass-and-editor-templates/6485552#6485552)

An example using attributes to do a sort of "known type" is here. http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DerivedTypeModelBinder&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Thanks for that! Wasn't really looking forward to the model binding. I ended up using the `DerivedTypeModelBinder