# MVC 3 Action Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

Maybe it will dup , but I didn't found anything that will help me to fix the problem.

I have Controller that can Have different ViewModels :

I would like to do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportToExcell(ILeadsViewModel model)
{


}
```

My ViewModels are:

```
public class ViewModelTest1 : ILeadsViewModel

public class ViewModelTest2 : ILeadsViewModel

public class ViewModelTest3 : ILeadsViewModel
```

Is there any chance to configure Unity return right instance for my ViewModel ?
If possible how ?
If possible , but you dont suggesting to this , please explain why.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm interested in how different they are and what that gives you.

Comment: Each viewModel contains nested Model that can differ depends on user request , and then data rendering different for each type of view model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom model binder for the `ILeadsViewModel` type that will return the proper view model based on some request properties. Here's [`an example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484972/viewmodel-with-listbaseclass-and-editor-templates) of a custom model binder. In this example I have used a Type property present in the request to `Activator.CreateInstance` the concrete view model but you could use Unity or whatever. But bear in mind that you should have some information present in the request that would allow the model binder to know which concrete instance of the view model to return.

Comment: Thanks man , I've justr ealized , that dependency injection into Action is useless , thank for pointing in rigth direction