# ASP.NET MVC Loading Partial View according to the type of the Model

Tags: inheritance, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a ViewModel object which contains a property of type Vehicle. This type is the base type and can be inherited from by other types like Car or Truck.

Now my View is bound to this ViewModel and for the Vehicle property, I'd like to use a partial View. Only this view would look different depending on the type of the Vehicle property.

What is the best (neatest) way to achieve that ? Should I check for the type in Razor directly and load the appropriate partial view  ?That does not sound too clever....

Answer (score 2):

You could use editor templates. I have written an [`example here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485552/29407) in which there is an abstract base view model and different editor templates are provided for each concrete type of the model. So basically instead of using partial views you could use editor templates and ASP.NET MVC will take care of automatically rendering the correct template based on the runtime type of your view model.