# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Posting Polymorphic Data Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, polymorphism

I have a viewmodel consisting of a handful of properties:

```
public class FooDataViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
/* Several Properties working as expected */

public ICollection<Foo> Foos {get; set;}

/* Validation working as expected */
}
```

Foo holds a few fields and works as expected:

```
public class Foo
{
/* Only a few basic properties, works as expected */
}
```

But I have some objects that are Foobar:

```
public class FooBar : Foo, IValidatableObject
{
/* Just a few more properties and some conditional validation */
}
```

I created a custom editor template for both Foo and FooBar.  For my edit view, I simply use '@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foos)' and editors for both Foo and FooBar are displayed. But when I submit to my HttpPost method, only Foo objects are created, and the FooBar specific data is lost.  How can I make sure that that the FooBar objects are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make sure that that the FooBar objects are created?

You will need to include this information in the request and write a custom model binder that is able to use this information and instantiate the proper type. I have illustrated the concept here: [ViewModel with List<BaseClass> and editor templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484972/viewmodel-with-listbaseclass-and-editor-templates)

Comment: The link was useful, and helped me to work through my problem.  That question was originally for MVC3 so I'll follow up by asking: were there any change/optimizations that would apply for MVC4?

Comment: No, there are absolutely no change/optimizations for MVC 4 in this aspect.