# How can I HTTP POST a dynamic-length collection of derived/"child" models in NET Framework MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8

Let's say I have an MVC Model called "Shape", and it is the base class to a number of derived classes which are specific shapes containing properties inherent to them.

```cs
public class Shape
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public int Radius { get; set; }
}

public class Triangle : Shape
{
    public string Type { get; set; }  // i.e. "isosceles", "equilateral", etc.
}
```

I have an MVC Controller with an action method that fetches a set of shapes (of varying kinds) from a database and attempts to render them on a page.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyShapes()
{
    // Collection of various kinds of shapes (i.e. Circles and Triangles).
    List<Shape> listOfShapes = GetShapesFromDatabase();
    return View(listOfShapes);
}
```

Here is a sample MVC View, which uses Razor Syntax. It takes the list of shapes and displays them on the page, while also offering the options to modify them, add new shapes, and saving the changes.

```
@model List<Shapes>

<p>Modify the shapes.</p>
@foreach (Shape object in Model)
{
    if (object is Circle)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_RenderCircle.cshtml", object)
    }
    else if (object is Triangle)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_RenderTriangle.cshtml", object)
    }
}
<button type="button">Add New Shape</button>
<button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
```

A sample PartialView:

```
@model Circle
<div>
    @* Pretend this is code that renders a circle *@
    
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Color)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Radius)
</div>
```

The question I have is: how can I set up the View(s) so that I can gather up all the various shapes on the page and send back a list of them (with their modified properties) to the Controller for database storage?

Currently, I serialize the data on the frontend using Javascript and send it over via AJAX. I'm well aware that this is a hacky workaround that doesn't follow the MVC model, which is why I'm looking for a better solution.

I read a little about EditorTemplates, but I'm not sure how to get them to apply to this scenario where the Model is a collection of derived classes.

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484972/viewmodel-with-listbaseclass-and-editor-templates/6485552#6485552

Comment: Thank you, reading that post helped me find a solution.